# Is there a T4 template to generate EntityTypeConfiguration from EDMX?

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco, t4, edmx, ef4-code-only

I'd like to go "code-only" from a mix of designer/code-first. I know it's possible to make a T4 template to generate the EntityTypeConfiguration classes and property mappings, but is there something like that already out there?

> "Why would you want to ..." != Answer // 8)

Comment: Remember to Accept answers if they are indeed what you were looking for or comment on it to give more detail or ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a **ADO.NET C# DbContext Fluent Generator** from [I.Fle (IFle)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=I.Fle) , it helps me a lot, just for vs 2010 look at: [download link here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c3351a9-bc39-4de1-ae91-c5ef427836d5) .